# maven super pom's profile properties inheritance at child poms

Tags: spring, maven, properties, profile

at my project there is 2 profiles and each profile has one property. 
But I could not use master's properties at child's resources.

Here is described clearly but it seems that there is only one pom file and the sample shown at there is not an multi-module maven project.

All I want to do is use this properties at spring level like changing the location of properties file.

```
 <profile>
        <id>p1</id>
        <properties>
            <properties.location>file:/apps-core1.properties</properties.location>
        </properties>
    </profile>
 <profile>

 <profile>
        <id>p2</id>
        <properties>
            <properties.location>file:/apps-core2.properties</properties.location>
        </properties>
    </profile>
 <profile>
```

and I want to use "properties.location" at every pom file I had, either main-resources or test-resources.

here is the spring usage

```
<context:property-placeholder location="\${properties.location}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it working with a multi-module project with:

- parent pom with `<modules />` config and your profiles
- module pom with following config

  ```
  <build>
     <resources>
        <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
           <includes>
              <include>**/*.xml</include>
           </includes>                
        </resource>
     </resources>
  </build>
  ```

see [maven resources and filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: I've already added these configurations and same for the test-resources. Now it is working for every module.

Comment: @Melih you should add to <testResources>